# preg_match string must start with alphabetical char

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a name field and I want to validate, so the first char must be alphabetical of the name and allow spaces and dashes after. I have this so for but it will allow "-" as first char.

```
preg_match("/^([a-z -])+$/i", $str)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being specific is the better option. But you can also use an assertion:

```
preg_match("/^(?![- ])([a-z -])+$/i", $str)
```

The `(?!..)` can exclude characters from occuring first. You could also use a positive assertion like `(?=\w)`.

Comment: I think lookbehind assertions are `(?<!)` and `(?<=)` respectively.

Comment: @BoltClock: It's not really a lookbehind, but a lookcurrent. It asserts the immediately *following* characters here

Comment: So the one by mario correct do i want lookbehind, lookcurrent or lookaheah. Thanks

Comment: @johncook: Use the code as in the example. We were just discussing the terminology here. (Technically it's mostly the same.)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but how would you have it so it cant end with a "-" :)

Comment: @johncook: Use `preg_match("/^(?![- ])([a-z -])+(?<![-])$/i", $str)` which would use a *negative lookbehind* `?<!` *assertion* this time.

Comment: @mario Thank you, your a hero! Thanks to everyone else also who commented!

Comment: @johncook: Btw, did you know about http://regular-expressions.info/ - it's a very comprehensive overview, yet mostly readable. And it also has some interesting pages on PHP, and some useful examples. But also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some cool regex tools.

Comment: @mario Thanks i will as reg expressions is a powerful thing in the right hands. With great power comes great responsibility ;P

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/^[a-z][a-z -]+$/i", $str)
```